# Direct link to apps in new Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

When instructing a domain admin to install an app from the legacy marketplace, we could just give them a direct link from which they could click an install/add button.  Is there an equivalent direct link for apps in the new marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the name of the app in the Chrome Webstore Developer Dashboard will take you to a standalone page for your app that you can share with others.

Answer (score 0):

See this - https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button

It's not a direct link unfortunately but serves a similar purpose.